# Node http-proxy find proxied URL

Tags: node-http-proxy

I'm trying to debug why I get a 404 from a proxied server when use `http-proxy`. Is there a way I can find out what the proxied URL is?

This is my current config:

```
app.all('/api/*', function(request, response, next) {
  return proxy.proxyRequest(request, response, {
    host: 'foo.com',
    port: 80
  });
});
```

Comment: was there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use request.url to get the URL of the request. For example, to print the URL to the console before proxying it:

```
app.all('/api/*', function(request, response, next) {
  console.log('Proxying ' + request.url);
  return proxy.proxyRequest(request, response, {
    host: 'foo.com',
    port: 80
  });
});
```